# How to restore a differential equation knowing its solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

How to restore a differential equation ( or system ) knowing its solution?
Suppose I have a rational function $y=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and I want to know if there is an differential equation $F(x,y,y',y'',\ldots )$ ( or system such equations)  such that $y$ is a solution of the equation. Is there any general way to construct $F(x,y,y',y'',\ldots )$ in an explicit way?

Comment: Take $F(x,y,y',...)=y-\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.

Comment: good joke :)...

Comment: The point he's making is that $F$ is very, very far from unique. But you can still ask what the set of all differential equations a certain function satisfies is.

Comment: It is not a joke. It is a solution to the problem you have written. But you probably haven't properly written what you really want to ask.  For example,   you said that the equation have the single solution $y=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. If the order of the differential equation is not zero, then under mild conditions on $F$ one often gets a family of solutions instead of a single solution. Having a family of solutions one gets a less trivial looking equation.

Comment: you are rigth, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing it as $gy=f$ and differentiating gives the ODE $gy'+g'y=f'$...

If you have a solution with $k$ differentiation constant(s) present then you obtain the DE by computing $y',…y^{(k)}$ and eliminating the integration constants from this system of $k+1$ equations for the $k+1$ variables $y^{(k)},C_1,...,C_k$.